# Why does appending a list by itself create an infinite list

Tags: python, list, recursion

```
l = [1, 2]
l.append(l)
>>>l
[1, 2, [...]] #l is an infinite list
```

Why does this create an infinite list instead of creating:

```
l = [1, 2]
l.append(l)
>>>l
[1, 2, [1, 2]]
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/397034/confusing-list-in-python-what-is-it

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you do:

```
l.append(l)
```

a *reference* to list `l` is appended to list `l`:

```
>>> l = [1, 2]
>>> l.append(l)
>>> l is l[2]
True
>>>
```

In other words, you put the list inside itself.  This creates an infinite reference cycle which is represented by `[...]`.

---

To do what you want, you need to append a *copy* of list `l`:

```
>>> l = [1, 2]
>>> l.append(l[:])  # Could also do 'l.append(list(l))' or 'l.append(l.copy())'
>>> l
[1, 2, [1, 2]]
>>> l is l[2]
False
>>>
```

Answer (score 2):

Easy, because each object will have a reference to itself in the third element. To achieve `[1, 2, [1, 2]]` then use a copy of the list.

```
l.append(l[:])
```