# Passing parameters in Python - Set 1

Tags: python

I have the below python code:

```
x = range(3)
x.append(x)
x[3][3][3][3][0] = 5
```

The value of x after this is [5, 1, 2, [...]].
But, I dont understand how the parameter is passed in the above context. Can anyone please help me understand?

Comment: Try printing `x` after each step.

Comment: Yes, I did that and observed the following output:[0, 1, 2]
[0, 1, 2, [...]]
[5, 1, 2, [...]]

Comment: @AgniswarBakshi, see my answer for the question marked as duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/a/38544046/4593127